# Can a CollapsiblePanelExtender expand from code behind?

Tags: c#

I have added a checkbox to the rows of a gridview that when clicked will expand a panel in the row.  My gridview needs to use paging, so I am saving in a session variable the state of the current page before the page change.  When the user clicks back to a page I am repopulating the checkboxes, but this does not expand the panels.  Is there away to expand the panels from the code behind?

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="Order Updated Records" ID="cbUR" Visible='<%# !DBNull.Value.Equals(Eval("AnyBox"))%>' /> 
<asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cInst" runat="server" TargetControlID="inst" Collapsed="true" AutoExpand="true" AutoCollapse="false" ExpandControlID="cbUR" CollapseControlID="cbUR" />
<asp:Panel ID="Inst" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInst" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="200" />
</asp:panel>
```

I tried adding the panel, textbox and panel extender from the code, but could not get it to work.  I read on a different post that the whole gridview would need to load from the code for this to work.

I would love to use something like

```
<asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cInst" runat="server" TargetControlID="inst" Collapsed='<%#!Convert.ToBoolean(rowItems[index].ToString()) %>' />
```

Would it be better not use the CollapsiblePanelExtender and find a different way to show the panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a public/protected method:

```
public bool IsCollapsed(object rowId) {
    //get row by ID here and return true if collapsed
    return ....
}
```

that would return a value for a row that needs to be expanded or collapsed.

and use it like:

```
Collapsed='<%# IsCollapsed(Eval("RowId")) %>'
```

where RowId is a property that represents the ID of the item.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Roland. I am having a issue with passing the rowid to IsCollapsed. I have Collapsed='<%# IsCollapsed(Eval("Container.DataItemIndex")) %>'. How do I get the ID of the row? The error is DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Container'.

Comment: Got it!  Collapsed='<%# IsCollapsed(Container.DataItemIndex) %>' works.  thanks for the help!